# второй параметр range (python)

Tags: python, range

Задача:

Дан список чисел. Определите, сколько в этом списке элементов, которые больше двух своих соседей, и выведите количество таких элементов. Крайние элементы списка никогда не учитываются, поскольку у них недостаточно соседей.

Объясните, пожалуйста, момент в решении:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
counter = 0
for i in range(1, len(a) - 1):
    # о боги, разве так можно писать?
    if a[i - 1] < a[i] > a[i + 1]:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Зачем в range от значения len(a) отнимать единицу, если второй параметр функции range  не включается, и для того, чтобы исключить последний элемент списка, по этой логике, можно было бы написать просто len(a)? (видимо, нельзя было бы, хочу понять , почему)

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле очень хороший вопрос!
Краткий ответ: чтобы не получить `IndexError: list index out of range`.
Но получить ее в данном случае можно не всегда. Давайте разберемся.

Как Вы правильно заметили:

> о боги, разве так можно писать? `if a[i - 1] < a[i] > a[i + 1]`

Действительно, так можно писать.
Это всего-навсего то же самое, что и

```
if a[i - 1] < a[i] and a[i] > a[i + 1]
```

То есть программа в цикле `for` пробегает по всем элементам списка (кроме первого и последнего) и последовательно спрашивает:

1. `a[i - 1] < a[i]` ? (наш элемент больше предыдущего?)
2. `a[i] > a[i + 1]` ? (наш элемент больше следующего?)

Причем второе условие проверяется только если выполнено первое (так работает оператор `and`).

Так (двойным неравенством) пишут ради экономии.

Теперь о том, почему это важно понимать.

Допустим, Вы предлагаете пробежаться не по всем элементам, кроме первого и последнего, а по всем, кроме только первого.

Рассмотрим конкретный пример, возьмем список: `a = [5,4,3]`.

Легко понять, что делает программа:

- На первой итерации она берет число 4 (не 5, потому что `range` стартует
  с 1, а не с 0) и спрашивает: 4>5? Получает ответ "нет", и после этого
  уже не проверят правого соседа (4>3 или нет)
- На второй итерации она берет число 3 и спрашивает: 3>4? Получает
  ответ "нет", и после этого уже не проверят правого соседа (которого,
  кстати, нет!)

И поэтому предложенный Вами вариант решения `for i in range(1, len(a))` здесь не даст ошибки!

Но теперь возьмем, например, `a = [3,4,5]`.

Тогда

- На первой итерации программа берет число 4 и спрашивает: 4>3?
  Получает ответ "да!",  И тогда проверяет правого соседа: 4>5? Но
  получает ответ "нет" и переходит к следующей итерации.
- На второй итерации она берет число 5: 5>4? "да!", и теперь программа
  хочет проверить правого соседа, но видит, что `i` вышел за пределы
  списка и сообщает об этом

> list index out of range

Поэтому, чтобы такой ошибки не было, авторы решения предлагают пробегать по всем числам, кроме первого и последнего.
Более того, по условию задачи нет никакой необходимости проверять первое и последнее число:

> Крайние элементы списка никогда не учитываются, поскольку у них
>   недостаточно соседей.

А теперь, пожалуй, самое интересное:
Возьмем `a = []`, то есть пустой список.
Логично предположить, что мы должны получить ошибку, т.к. у нас нет ни первого, ни последнего элемента.

Но мы получим ответ: 0.

Дело в том, что python, грубо говоря, предварительно проверяет, нужен ли вообще цикл.
Например, если список пустой, то цикл не нужен никогда.
Или если список состоит из 1 элемента, а мы хотим пробежаться с 3-го по 10-ый элемент, то цикл просто не срабатывает!

Но если мы в списке из 10 элементов хотим пробежать с 5 по 20, то цикл будет работать (итерировать) до тех пор, пока не выйдет за пределы списка и только тогда будет ошибка.

Поэтому изначальное решение хорошо как раз тем, что никогда не будет давать `IndexError`.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не вылезти за границу массива в `... > a[i + 1]:` при проверке предпоследнего элемента массива. На последней итерации цикла:

```
i равно len(a)-2
i+1 равно len(a)-1, т.е. индекс самого последнего элемента массива
```